# Changing the default user while using REST framework JWT

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a proxied user model:

```
class TheDude(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And I'm using the Django REST framework JWT to do JWT auth in the REST API.

I'd like to get the user object from the request but currently it's a User object. Because it's proxied I can't use `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. I've tried doing a middleware component to override the user in the request but it's not set at that stage. I've also tried using `JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` however my function isn't called so I can't set it there either.

If I want to be able to get `TheDude` object when I call `request.user` instead of `User` in my views, how would I do this while authing using the REST framework JWT Auth library?

**EDIT**

I've added

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'myapp.authentication.MyCustomJWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}
```

to my settings.py and my

```
class MyCustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_model = TheDude
```

Which is called correctly however when I get the user from request in my serialiser, it's still of type `User` and not `TheDude`

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user_test = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user_test')

    def get_user_test(self, obj):
        print(type(self.context['request'].user))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use the proxy model by overriding the [`JWTAuthentication`](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py#L19) authentication class and setting your proxy user model as the `user_model` like so:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication


class MyCustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_model = TheDude
```

Say you add this class on `myapp/authentication.py`, you can then apply this custom authentication class as one of the default authentication classes in your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.authentication.MyCustomJWTAuthentication',
        ...
        
    )
    ...
}
```

Or just apply it to certain views you want:

```
from myapp.authentication import MyCustomJWTAuthentication


class CertainAPIViewThatNeedsTheDude(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (MyCustomJWTAuthentication, )
```

This should in turn give you a `request.user` that is a `TheDude` instance.

Comment: I'm using djangorestframework-jwt rather than djangorestframework-simplejwt but I'll look into moving across. I'll see if I can modify your answer into the different library.

Comment: I see. That package seems to be unmaintained, and uses rather old django versions. Anyway you can do the same idea with [`authenticate_credentials`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L47)

Comment: I think I'll see about transferring it to a maintained package. I inherited this app unfortunately.

Comment: I've moved auth library and implemented this code however I'm still getting `User` object in my serialisers when I do `self.context['request'].user`

Comment: Can you update your question with latest changes? Also with the current settings

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Can you also check if the init was reached? Maybe another authentication class has successfully authenticated causing this new class to not be called. In that case, try to put it at the top of the list of authentication classes

Comment: Yes it was, it was just a default object though but I think that's expected.

Comment: Can you share the view? Maybe try to use only that authentication class in the view